# Show Other Pages To People Entering via Desktop Computer?

Tags: wordpress

If the visitor enters my site, I would like to show another page if it is coming from a computer. How can I do this? Mobile users entering my site can see the default theme homepage.

Comment: There are many ways to detect what device people are browsing your site on. Research device detection (most of it will come up as 'mobile detection' but th e principle is the same.  https://webplatform.github.io/docs/concepts/Detecting_device_and_browser/  Once the code knows the device it can then serve up different content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this approach. Place this code to functions.php. Also, custom-template.php needs to be inside wp-content/themes/your-theme directory

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'salient_child_template_include' );

function salient_child_template_include($original_template)
{
    if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $your_template_path = get_theme_file_path('custom-template.php');
        return $your_template_path;
   }

   return $original_template;
}
```

Comment: Are you a hero? I think you're a hero. Because you saved my whole day. THANK YOU

Comment: Changes the homepage, but does not redirect the articles when clicked. Why?

Comment: If I understand right, maybe try to check inside `wp_is_mobile` if the article page for example
`if ( $original_template === 'article' ) { return get_them_file_path('desktop-article.php') ''}`

Comment: No, what I want to say is that when I want to open an article, it goes into the loop, and it's always Page custom-template.php(my page) in front of me.

Comment: Please, then check template only if you need for toggling.
Try to replace `if ( ! wp_is_mobile () )` with
`if ( ! wp_is_mobile() && $original_template === 'template-for-toggling.php')`
Where `$orginal_template` for toggling you could define via `var_dump`

Comment: I solved this problem with your support. I shared the codes.